# workflow_dispatch Button "Run Workflow" is not show to my workflow

Tags: github, github-actions, devops

Here is my code

```
name: Build Test

on:
  workflow_dispatch: {}
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build:
    name: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Run a one-line script
        run: echo Hello, world!
```

and why in workflow don't show the button

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGX1z.png)

I try this code on other repo and button show but this workflow not work

Answer (score 0):

on line `workflow_dispatch: {}`

If you don't want to provide any arguments to workflow_dispatch, just leave it as it is.

try this:

```
on: 
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
```

Comment: still didn't work for me

Comment: I checked on my Github environment, it is working. It was throwing some warning though regarding using v2 of the checkout action. Maybe you should upgrade it to current version, v4, and try again.